# Relative path is not considered for background image configured in component css when ng serve Angular app

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, background-image

I have two `div` with id `div1` and `div2`, I need to set **two different background image** for them, the images have the same name but located in different folders, so i configured as below,

**app.component.html :**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**app.component.css:**

`background-image` with different path for each `div`.

```
#div1 {
  background-image: url('../assets/images/videos/back.jpg');
  /* other styles */
}

#div2 {
  background-image: url('../assets/images/blogs/back.jpg');
   /* other styles */
}
```

**Problem :**

Both div shows the same background image while i serve the app using `ng serve` .

Please note that **path to both images are different but the name is same**

**Reason :**

When checked in developer tools of the browser, the style is coming as below,

```
#div1 [_ngcontent-c0] {
    background-image: url(back.jpg);
    /* other styles */
}

#div2 [_ngcontent-c0] {
        background-image: url(back.jpg);
        /* other styles */
}
```

that is Instead of `url('../assets/images/blogs/back.jpg')` it is coming as `url(back.jpg)` - with out the relative path, hence both showing the same image in background.

**Question :**

Is this an expected behavior for angular ? If not what am I missing here ?

Comment: may you try it with background property?

Comment: can you build your app and check what will be in dist folder?

Comment: @FatemeFazli Same with background property as well.

Comment: @AmirArbabian , when building It creates a copy of each file in new names into the root directory.. So it work fine - still its not using the original file, but the copy of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths in CSS should be relative to the base URL, not relative to the component within the `src` directory. Therefore remove the leading `..` from the path but make sure you have the leading slash:

```
#div1 {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/videos/back.jpg');
}

#div2 {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/blogs/back.jpg');
}
```

Based on experimentation, I can see that when using a path relative to the source code, the CLI creates a copy of the referenced image and drops it at the root of the `dist` folder. This causes the `dist` folder look as follows:

```
/dist
  // This is the image that the CLI created 
  // and your component is referencing, but 
  // you want to reference the images in the
  // assets folder.
  back.jpg
  /assets
      /images
          /videos
              back.jpg
          /blogs
              back.jpg
```

Comment: Path relative to the base URL works fine..  Just like you said, CLI created a copy in into root directory , build renames the files to unique names as well, so it doesn't make any issue as well. but this issue is only when serves with `ng serve`. so either It should be mandatory to use path relate to base URL, or it works both with build and ng serve same way right ? isn't it odd ?

Comment: has problem if using relative if there are duplicate asset file names (different content/image), they overwrite each other in the root, and not consistent which one wins. That's my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do an inline style for mine to work

```
<section id="hero" style="background-image: url(./assets/pic.jpg)">
```