# Angular: Using base-href in combination with scss urls

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I'm trying to deploy my Angular app to a server with a subdomain: website.com/magazine/.
So to this I'm running the angular-cli command

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/magazine/
```

My images are in src/assets/images folder.
When I do this:

```
background-image:url('./assets/images/.....')
```

the images I refer to via background-image in scss are not showing up because he's trying to fetch the images from website.com/assets/...., ignoring the subdomain.

When I do this (say in sr/app/components/component/component.scss):

```
background-image: url('../../../assets/images/...')
```

It works, but the images are stored in the root of the dist folder, which I don't want.

When i do this:

```
background-image:url('~/assets/images/...');
```

or this

```
background-image:url('./assets/images/...');
```

I get an error

```
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)
```

What I want is that I can refer to the images and keep my relative images path in tact. How do I accomplish this?

I'm using Angular 11 and angular cli 11.1.4

Comment: I’d expect background-image:url('assets/images/.....') to work..?

Comment: url('assets/images/...') isn't working. In my main.scss I import several other scss files like @import 'layout/footer'. And during build I get the error Can't resolve './layout/assets/images/etc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the angular team itself is not really helpful https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18043 regarding this issue. Which is mind-boggling given how standard this use case it...

I am using **Angular 11**. I am using the `filter` rule but it of course works with `bacground-url` or any other css rule which uses a `url('')` path value.

You can inline the style as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66974900/7485690, it will get saved **only** into the correct folder `/assets/filter` and it works with `--base-href`

```html
  <div class="log-wrap" style="filter: url('./assets/filter/round-clip-path.svg#goo');">
```

Your solution with the relative path works as well but it copies the file into the root folder, so now you have one located in `/assets/filter` and one in root `/`.

```css
.log-wrap {
  filter: url("../../../assets/filter/round-clip-path.svg#goo");
}
```

There is one more solution which works the same way but is easier to write:

```css
.log-wrap {
  filter: url("src/assets/filter/round-clip-path.svg#goo");
}
```

Don't forget to **disable cache** in developer console when experimenting with deployment.